# Why does node-oracledb make more number of connections than max pool value?

Tags: node.js, oracle, oracle11g, node-oracledb

I have a application where I have configured maxpool to a certain number. But the connections to the db are exceeding that number. Is max pool value supposed to limit the number of connections, then why its behaving so? Is there any other way to limit connections?

Comment: You are not saying if the sessions you see are all from the connection pool. Probably not. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/search/?q=max session&library=en%2Fdatabase%2Foracle%2Foracle-database%2F21) how to limit the sessions on DB level.

Comment: Update your question with a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Are you sure you're only creating the pool once in the app? Are you killing and restarting the app - Maybe there is some delayed DB clean out waiting for TCP timeouts on the connections?